# Synonymise [alignment] and [sequence-alignment]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While asking a question here, I noticed that [alignment](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alignment) and [sequence-alignment](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence-alignment) both exist. They appear to be synonymous; indeed, the [alignment](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alignment) description reads, in its entirety:

> These questions are about sequence alignment.

I understand that there's been some [past debate](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/129/3144) about how to deal with alignment-related tags, but as best I can tell these two in particular are, unambiguously, exact synonyms. Synyomise them?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me…